# Should I use brackets [] or .at() for array access?

Tags: c++, arrays

Since the `at()` function in C++ arrays and vectors provides out-of-bounds checking and there is not a significant performance difference in using `operator[]` instead, should one ever use brackets for array access?

Perhaps only in performance-critical code?

Comment: Since you are a good person, you will know whether your indices are within bounds, and you don't need the vector to check that for you redundantly. Use the square brackets.

Comment: _"there is not a significant performance difference in using operator[] instead"_ [citation needed]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't use any of them. `std::vector` provides iteration capabilities that rarely make necessary to explicitly access an item by index.

To answer your question, following the *don't pay for what you don't use*, if you know that you are not going to go out of bounds there is no need to use `at()`.

Otherwise you should always check a pointer for not being `nullptr` every time you are going to dereference it, but in practice you don't do it if you are sure that it's a valid pointer.

Comment: What std::vector iteration capabilities? Would you mind providing a link or further describing?

Comment: `<algorithm>` header provides functions to do almost everything on STL containers without the need of ever looping over a `std::vector` and retrieve objects by index. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm

Answer (score 9):

You should use `[]` when you are certain that no "out-of bounds" access will happen.

You should use `at()` when "out of bounds" access *may* happen and you are prepared to either deal with that (by catching the exception and doing something sensible) or your program crashing is ok (which it would anyway had you used `[]`, just in an undefined manner).

You can also use `.at()` temporarily while developing (or debugging) the application, to make it easier to debug out-of-bounds accesses (since you'll get an exception rather than just undefined behaviour), and usually you don't care much about a slight performance hit during initial development and testing. Then you can switch your calls from `.at()` to `operator[]` when you are sure that they are correct and don't really need to debug them further.

Answer (score 4):

that later changing from at(i) to operator is quite a hassle. Therefore I agree  with Jesper.

To catch out of bounds problems you can e.g. either use valgrind or if you are using GCC compile with -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG. See [GCC Debug mode](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode.html) for more info.

Comment: It may be a pain, but it is more of a pain if you don't have these debugging facilities, and the choice is either try and fix the issue by replacing a few `[ ]` calls with `at()`, or spending hours debugging.

Comment: Is it better to use asserts for bounds checking instead of at()? Since the asserts will be removed in a release build?

Comment: @J-Win The issue with `assert()` is that it *is* removed in a release build.  What if the bug only appears in the release build?

Comment: Ok that makes sense then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should start out by using `at()`, since we are confident that our programs don't have boundary access issues.  Thus we start out using `[ ]` immediately.

However, if we go by the posts on SO (by usually new programmers) there have been numerous questions concerning vector access that could have been solved easily if the `at()` were used to detect boundary issues.

Given this experience, use `at()` for debugging purposes when you suspect that you are going out of bounds, or if there is a hint that you may be going out-of-bounds.

Comment: _"since we are confident that our programs don't have boundary access issues"_ We are?

Comment: I write that with some sarcasm, but good programmers do have that confidence.

Comment: I have confidence that I do not have that confidence.

Comment: One should always code defensively and act as if all hell will break loose at every line of code.